# Can't convert geometry from Dgn file to shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, gdal, ogr, dgn

I am using below codes to try convert geometry from a Dgn file to shapefile. But, I can't exit the Feature reading loop.

Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

Please download the .dgn file from the link: [DgnFile](http://www.mediafire.com/?6q5es4zha2fr2h6)

```
bool Convert()
{
    OGRRegisterAll();
    OGRDataSource       *poDS,  *poSHPDS;
    const char *pszDriverName = "ESRI Shapefile";
    OGRSFDriver *poDriver;
    poDriver = OGRSFDriverRegistrar::GetRegistrar()->GetDriverByName(
                  pszDriverName );

    // Open file DGN
    poDS = OGRSFDriverRegistrar::Open( sourceFile, FALSE );

    if( poDS == NULL )

    {
         cout << "Error opeing DGN file." << endl;
         return false;
    } 
    // Create datasource for file shp
  poSHPDS = poDriver->CreateDataSource(destinationPath,NULL);

  if( poSHPDS == NULL )
  {
        cout << "Error creating shape file." << endl;
        return false;
  }     
  OGRLayer  *poLayer, *poSHPLayer; 

  // Get Layer from DGN file

  poLayer = poDS->GetLayer(0);

  // Create new Layer of SHP file

  poSHPLayer = poSHPDS->CreateLayer (shpFileName, NULL, wkbPolygon, NULL);

  if(poSHPLayer == NULL)

  {

          cout << "Error creating Layer of Shape File." << endl;

          return false;
  }

  OGRFeature *poFeature;

  poLayer->ResetReading(); 

  **while( (poFeature = poLayer->GetNextFeature()) != NULL ) // Can't exit this loop** 

  {

        OGRGeometry *poGeometry;
        poGeometry = poFeature->GetGeometryRef();

        // if feature is a Polygon
        if( poGeometry != NULL && (wkbFlatten(poGeometry->getGeometryType()) == wkbPolygon ) )
        {
                OGRFeature *poSHPFeature;
                //Create new Feature shape file
                poSHPFeature = OGRFeature::CreateFeature (poSHPLayer->GetLayerDefn());
                poSHPFeature->SetGeometry (poGeometry);
                OGRPolygon *poPolygon = (OGRPolygon*) poSHPFeature->GetGeometryRef();

                poLayer->SetSpatialFilter(poGeometry);
                poLayer->ResetReading ();

         }
         OGRFeature::DestroyFeature( poFeature );

    }
    OGRDataSource::DestroyDataSource( poDS );
    OGRDataSource::DestroyDataSource( poSHPDS );
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you don't want to reset the read inside the loop? (i.e. try removing poLayer->ResetReading ();)

Comment: @BradHards : Do you know how to split polygons if there is a polygon contain another small polygon. Please see my image: http://www.mediafire.com/download/62b9u4752jj0v47/image.png . After converting from dgn to shp, I can't choose the small polygon. Thank you very much

Comment: That looks like a completely different question.

Comment: @BradHards : I posted another question at here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62428/asking-about-convert-dgn-to-shp-and-ogrlayersetspatialfilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ResetReading() call inside the loop is "taking you back to the start" on each iteration. You'll need to remove the

```
poLayer->ResetReading ();
```

line to continue iterating over the layer features.